# Is the pre-image (through a measurable function) of a Lebesgue-measurable set also measurable?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

As I wrote in the title, I was wondering if it was true that given $f$ a Lebesgue-measurable function,and $E$ a measurable set, we have that $f^{-1} (E)$ is also measurable, and (if not) to show a proof or a counterexmple. I have thought that since the counnterimage of every borelian set is a borelian, I had to use some "patological" sets, such as Cantor set or Vitali set.

P.S. I would like to prove it in $\mathbb{R}$, without considering the possibility that $f(a)= \pm \infty$ for some $a$.

Comment: Here there is a bit of a terminological issue. In general measure theory, given two measurable spaces $(X,\mathcal E)$ and $(Y,\mathcal F)$, where $\mathcal E$ and $\mathcal F$ are $\sigma$-algebras, a function $f:(X,\mathcal E)\to(Y,\mathcal F)$ is said to be measurable if for all $F\in\mathcal F$,  $f^{-1}(F)\in E$. However, albeit the privileged $\sigma$-algebra on euclidean spaces $\Bbb R^n$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, it is costumary for the case $Y=\Bbb R$ to call *measurable* (-period-) a measurable function $f:(X,\mathcal E)\to (\Bbb R,\text{Borel})$ in the aforementioned sense.

Comment: A consequence of this is that, although the result "preimage of measurable set is measurable" holds in the sense of the first definition, this does not consistently carry on to the terminology commonly used in real analysis. Or, rather, the correct way to translate it would be "preimage of a Borel set under a measurable function is Lebesgue-measurable".

Comment: I really hate this terminology breakdown. It's one of the real pitfalls of measure theory.

Answer (score 1):

Since preimages of closed sets are measurable, you should focus on sets of measure zero. In particular, if you can find an injective measurable function $f$ that sends a set of positive measure $P$ to a set of zero measure, you can find a counterexample by restricting $f$ to a nonmeasurable set $N \subset P$ and setting $E = f(N)$.

A standard example uses the Cantor function. Let $c : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be the Cantor function and let $g(x) = c(x) + x$. Then $g : [0,1] \to [0,2]$ is continuous and strictly increasing. Look at the function $f = g^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok, so let me try to sum up to check if I've understood. First you find a measurable function that sends a set with positive measure in a set of measure 0. Then you use the known fact that every set of positive measure contains a non- measurable subset. You take the image of this non-measurable subset. The image will have measure zero and thus be measurable. You take the pre-image and it's done.